# I cannot used Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.green[500]), error

Tags: flutter

The following assertion was thrown building Icon(IconData(U+0E838), color: Color(0xff4caf50),

Comment: can you share the exact error message

Comment: Sorry dear, provided details not enough us to write something that useful for you. How about relavent code snippet and error log message.

Comment: I am new with flutter and I was struggling the structure on putting the icon. But thanks to you both try to understands my problem I resolved the issue. `Icon(Icons.star)`

Answer (score 1):

Invalid placement of the icon widget.

it suppost to be like this.

```
child: Icon(
    Icons.star,
    size: 25.0,
    color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
  ),
```

or

```
child: Row(
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.star),
                Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
              ],
            ),
```